# Upgrade to Rails 4: order multiple columns in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have a model `Post` and it has_many `Comments`. `Post` has two attributes `fromTime` and `toTime` as dates. In Post model I have following codes:

```
has_many :comments, as: :available, order: "fromTime, toTime", dependent: :destroy
```

I recently upgraded my rails from `3.2` to `4.0`. Now, when I run the tests, I get deprecation warning that `:order is deprecated`. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Note: for a single column I can get rid of this deprecation warning easily with ->{order(:fromTime)}. Please refer to [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/400-what-s-new-in-rails-4?view=asciicast)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `has_many :comments, as: :available,  -> { order "fromTime, toTime" }, dependent: destroy`

Comment: **:order** is deprecated in recent version. You will have to use scope.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

Comment: Hi Saroj, thanks for the answer. But, I am getting another error `Invalid mix of scope block and deprecated finder options on ActiveRecord association` when I use your suggestion.

Comment: for order and conditions together do something like `->{where("toTime is null or toTime >=?", Time.now.utc).order("fromTime, toTime")}`